# AJAX Loading Animation - What about Bots?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a php file which get's a lot of data of a database (called test.php). The starting script of my website (index.php) shows a loading animation, loads the test.php with ajax, and displays it afterwards. The problem there is that Bots like Facebook, Google, Twitter etc. can't see the website, because they don't use javascript.

How can I provide the content without javascript to Bots, and as I said above to normal users?

Comment: here is a good article but you can google and findout better articles sure http://www.webseoanalytics.com/blog/googles-ajax-crawling-scheme-and-its-effects-on-seo/

Comment: How should I use this in my case?

Comment: this is just an input, don't know, try with hidden links that fb and google can parse for example